# Laravel 5.1 unique email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use the following rule in my code as per the documentation, however it is not working:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name'        => 'required',
        'last_name'         => 'required',
        'email'             => 'required|unique:users,email,:email',
    ];
}
```

It comes back with `The email has already been taken.`

I am trying to say if the users email is not unique then throw an error, except for the current user id.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it's worth noting that it can be considered a security flaw to force users to have unique email addresses. This is because if an attacker wants to know whether certain email addresses have been registered on a system, he can find out simply by attempting to change his address to the target address. With an automated tool and a database of email addresses (ie spam lists or hacked from other sites), an attacker could very quickly draw up a good profile of your user-base. This may or may not be an issue for you, but can be a doorward leading to additional ways of attacking you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the unique rule an ID to ignore. Try this:

```
return [
    'first_name'        => 'required',
    'last_name'         => 'required',
    'email'             => 'required|unique:users,email,' . Auth::user()->id
];
```

*Note: This assumes you are using Laravel's Auth class.*

Comment: Thanks but it's not the current logged in user. It's a user the administrator is editing.  So I guess I could use Request instead of Auth?